# Conflicts in AutoMapper and AutoFixture

Tags: automapper, autofixture

I have 2 classes, Class1 should be mapped to Class2. I do mapping with **AutoMapper**. I'd like to test my configuration of the mapper and for this purposes I'm using **AutoFixture**. Source class Class1 has property of type IList<>, destination class Class2 has a similar property but of type IEnumerable<>. To simplify test preparation I'm using **AutoFixture** (with **AutoMoqCustomization**) to initialize both source and destination objects. But after initializing property of type IEnumerable<> with AutoFixture, AutoMapper can't map the property.

Error text:

Error mapping types.

> Mapping types: Class1 -> Class2 ConsoleApplication1.Class1 ->
>   ConsoleApplication1.Class2
>
> Type Map configuration: Class1 -> Class2 ConsoleApplication1.Class1 ->
>   ConsoleApplication1.Class2
>
> Property: Items

Could anybody help me to configure either AutoMapper or AutoFixture to make the mapping work? As a workaround I can assign null to the destination property, but I do not want to do this in the each test.

Simplified example of code:

```
public class AutoMapperTests
{
    public static void TestCollectionsProperty()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ItemClass1, ItemClass2>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
        });

        var src = new Class1();
        src.Items = new List<ItemClass1>()
        {
            new ItemClass1() { Text = "111" },
            new ItemClass1() { Text = "222" }
        };

        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var dst = fixture.Create<Class2>();

        Mapper.Map(src, dst); //Error at this line of code
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public IList<ItemClass1> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public IEnumerable<ItemClass2> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemClass1
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class ItemClass2
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Code as posted doesn't compile, as (AFICT) `Mapper.CreateMap` has been deprecated and removed from AutoMapper. Please update repro code, or post a list of NuGet packages in use, including their version numbers.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I've updated the example

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an AutoFixture issue per se. You can reproduce it without AutoFixture by instead creating `dst` like this:

```
var dst = new Class2();
dst.Items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(_ => new ItemClass2());
```

This will produce a similar error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q45437098.ItemClass2]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q45437098.ItemClass2]'

That ought to be fairly self-explanatory: `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<int, ItemClass2>` doesn't implement `IList<ItemClass2>`. AutoMapper attempts to make that cast, and fails.

The simplest fix is probably to avoid populating `dst`:

```
var dst = new Class2();
```

If you *must* use AutoFixture for this, you can do it like this:

```
var dst = fixture.Build<Class2>().OmitAutoProperties().Create();
```

Unless the `Class2` constructor does something complex, however, I don't see the point of using AutoFixture in that scenario.

If, on the other hand, you do need `dst` to be populated, you just need to ensure that `dst.Items` is convertible to `IList<ItemClass2>`. One way to do that would be like this:

```
var dst = fixture.Create<Class2>();
dst.Items = dst.Items.ToList();
```

You could create a Customization to make sure that this happens automatically, but if you need help with that, please ask a new question (if you don't find one that already answers that question).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for your problem. As @Mark Seemann already told, `Mapper.CreateMap` has been deprecated, so this example is using the new structure.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ItemClass1, ItemClass2>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>();
});

var src = new Class1();
src.Items = new List<ItemClass1>()
{
    new ItemClass1() { Text = "111" },
    new ItemClass1() { Text = "222" }
};

var dest = Mapper.Map<Class1, Class2>(src);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but problem is that I need to use void method Mapper.Map<Class1, Class2>(src, dst); and it doesn't work. When I use method which return destination object, then everything works fine even with old version of AutoMapper where CreateMap is a static method of Mapper class.

Answer (score 0):

AM requires IList because you're mapping to an existing list and that works by calling IList.Add.